# Delphi ActionMainMenu in a TitleBar

Tags: delphi

In a TitleBarPanel I have placed an ActionMainMenu. That works fine. Including the submenus.
However, I am experiencing 2 problems that I cannot solve.

I would like the submenus in 2 columns. Actually I can't find anything about that.

I also want to place a separator somewhere. Same, I can't find anything about it.

With a normal MainMenu, a ColumBreak is simple. Then I do this: Items.Break := mbBarBreak; But that doesn't work with an ActionMainMenu.

With a normal MainMenu a separator is simple. Then I do this: SubItem.Caption := '-'; Then a separator line can be seen.

But that doesn't work with an ActionMainMenu. Can anyone help me with this?

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  Vcl.ActnCtrls,
  Vcl.ActnMan,
  Vcl.ActnMenus,
  Vcl.ActnList,
  Vcl.TitleBarCtrls,
  Vcl.PlatformDefaultStyleActnCtrls;

const AchtergrondKleur = clBtnFace;
      VoorGrondKeur    = clBlack;
      InAktiefVoorgrondKleur = clRed;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    TitleBarPanel: TTitleBarPanel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure Call_Definieer_CustomTitleBar;
    procedure Call_Definieer_ActionMainmenuBar;
    procedure Call_ActionManager_MainMenu_Items;
    procedure Call_Actionmanager_SubMenu_Items;
    procedure Call_Standaard_Actie(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;
  Actionmanager : TActionManager;
  ActionMainMenuBar : TActionMainMenuBar;
  ActionBarItem : TActionBarItem;
  MainMenuItem : TCustomAction;
  SubMenuItem: TActionClientItem;
  ActionClientItem: TActionClientItem;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Definieer het MainForm
  MainForm.WindowState := wsMaximized;

  //Definieer CustomTitleBar
  Call_Definieer_CustomTitleBar; //Unit Diversen

  //Definieer ActionManager
  ActionManager := TActionManager.Create(MainForm);

  //Definieer ActionMainMenuBar
  Call_Definieer_ActionMainmenuBar; //Unit Diversen

  //Definieer ActionBar
  ActionBarItem := ActionManager.ActionBars.Add;
  ActionBarItem.ActionBar := ActionMainMenuBar;

  //Definieer en voeg een Actie toe aan ActionManager
  Call_ActionManager_MainMenu_Items; //Unit Diversen

  //Definieer en voeg een SubActie toe aan ActionManager
  Call_Actionmanager_SubMenu_Items; //Unit Diversen
end;

(* Definieer CustomTitleBar *)
procedure TMainForm.Call_Definieer_CustomTitleBar;
begin
  MainForm.CustomTitleBar.Control := MainForm.TitleBarPanel;
  MainForm.CustomTitleBar.Enabled := True;
  MainForm.CustomTitleBar.SystemHeight := false;
  MainForm.CustomTitleBar.Height := 35;
  MainForm.CustomTitleBar.CaptionAlignment := taCenter;
  MainForm.CustomTitleBar.ShowCaption := true;
  MainForm.CustomTitleBar.ShowIcon := true;
  MainForm.CustomTitleBar.SystemColors  := false;
  MainForm.CustomTitleBar.SystemButtons := false;
  MainForm.CustomTitleBar.InitTitleBarColors;
  MainForm.CustomTitleBar.BackgroundColor         := AchtergrondKleur;
  MainForm.CustomTitleBar.ForegroundColor         := VoorGrondKeur;
  MainForm.CustomTitleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor   := AchtergrondKleur;
  MainForm.CustomTitleBar.ButtonForegroundColor   := VoorGrondKeur;
  MainForm.CustomTitleBar.InactiveBackgroundColor := AchtergrondKleur;
  MainForm.CustomTitleBar.InactiveForegroundColor := InAktiefVoorgrondKleur;
  MainForm.CustomTitleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor := AchtergrondKleur;
  MainForm.CustomTitleBar.ButtonInactiveForegroundColor := InAktiefVoorgrondKleur;
  MainForm.CustomTitleBar.ButtonHoverBackgroundColor := AchtergrondKleur + 130;
  MainForm.CustomTitleBar.ButtonHoverForegroundColor := clRed;
  MainForm.CustomTitleBar.Invalidate;
end; //Call_Definieer_CustomTitleBar

(* Definieer ActionMainMenuBar *)
procedure TMainForm.Call_Definieer_ActionMainmenuBar;
var Teller : byte;
begin
  ActionMainMenuBar := TActionMainMenuBar.Create(MainForm);
  ActionMainMenuBar.Parent := MainForm.TitleBarPanel; //Dit bepaalt de plaats
  ActionMainMenuBar.Align := alCustom;
  ActionMainMenuBar.Left := 30;
  ActionMainMenuBar.Width := 0; //Dit is een Init
  ActionMainMenuBar.Width := 200;
  ActionMainMenuBar.Height := MainForm.CustomTitleBar.Height;
  //ActionMainMenubar.OnPaint := MainForm.ActionMainMenuBarPaint;
  ActionMainMenuBar.DoubleBuffered := true;
  ActionMainMenuBar.Transparent := false;//true;
  ActionMainMenuBar.ActionManager := ActionManager;
  ActionMainMenuBar.ParentBackground := false;//true;
end; //Call_Definieer_ActionMainmenuBar

(* MainMenu HoofdItems toevoegen *)
procedure TMainForm.Call_ActionManager_MainMenu_Items;
var Teller : integer;
begin
  //Definieer en voeg een actie toe aan ActionManager
  MainMenuItem := TCustomAction.Create(MainForm);
  MainMenuItem.Caption := 'Eerste Item';
  ActionClientItem := ActionManager.ActionBars[0].Items.Add;
  ActionClientItem.Action := MainMenuItem;

  MainMenuItem := TCustomAction.Create(MainForm);
  MainMenuItem.Caption := 'Tweede Item';
  ActionClientItem := ActionManager.ActionBars[0].Items.Add;
  ActionClientItem.Action := MainMenuItem;
end; //Call_ActionManager_MainMenu_Items

procedure TMainForm.Call_Actionmanager_SubMenu_Items;
var SubAction : TCustomAction;
begin
   //
   SubAction := TCustomAction.Create(MainForm);
   SubAction.Caption := 'SubItem_1';
   SubmenuItem := ActionManager.ActionBars[0].
                                Items[0].
                                Items.Add;
   SubAction.OnExecute := MainForm.Call_Standaard_Actie;
   SubMenuItem.Action := SubAction; //Caption in Submenu laten zien

   //
   SubAction := TCustomAction.Create(MainForm);
   SubAction.Caption := 'SubItem_2';
   SubmenuItem := ActionManager.ActionBars[0].
                                Items[0].
                                Items.Add;
   SubAction.OnExecute := MainForm.Call_Standaard_Actie;
   SubMenuItem.Action := SubAction; //Caption in Submenu laten zien
   

   //Here i would like a separator <------------------------

   //
   SubAction := TCustomAction.Create(MainForm);
   SubAction.Caption := 'SubItem_3';
   SubmenuItem := ActionManager.ActionBars[0].
                                Items[0].
                                Items.Add;
   SubAction.OnExecute := MainForm.Call_Standaard_Actie;
   SubMenuItem.Action := SubAction; //Caption in Submenu laten zien

   // Hier zou een kolombreak moeten komen

   //
   SubAction := TCustomAction.Create(MainForm);
   SubAction.Caption := 'SubItem_4';
   SubmenuItem := ActionManager.ActionBars[0].
                                Items[0].
                                Items.Add;
   SubAction.OnExecute := MainForm.Call_Standaard_Actie;
   SubMenuItem.Action := SubAction; //Caption in Submenu laten zien

   //
   SubAction := TCustomAction.Create(MainForm);
   SubAction.Caption := 'SubItem_5';
   SubmenuItem := ActionManager.ActionBars[0].
                                Items[0].
                                Items.Add;
   SubAction.OnExecute := MainForm.Call_Standaard_Actie;
   SubMenuItem.Action := SubAction; //Caption in Submenu laten zien

   //
   SubAction := TCustomAction.Create(MainForm);
   SubAction.Caption := 'SubItem_6';
   SubmenuItem := ActionManager.ActionBars[0].
                                Items[0].
                                Items.Add;
   SubAction.OnExecute := MainForm.Call_Standaard_Actie;
   SubMenuItem.Action := SubAction; //Caption in Submenu laten zien
end;

(* SubMenu Standaard Actie*)
procedure TMainForm.Call_Standaard_Actie(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Actie uitgevoerd: ');
end;

end.
```

Comment: Have you looked at `Vcl.ActnMan.TActionClientItem.NewCol` and `Vcl.ActnMan.TActionClientItem.Separator`?

Answer (score 0):

I did make a little bit progress. Adding this code inbetween the submenuItems give a real separator line:

`SubmenuItem := ActionManager.ActionBars[0].Items[0].Items.Add; SubmenuItem.Caption := '-';`

So One problem is solved. Now i look for the colomnBreak

Comment: It is a pitty. SubmenuItem.NewCol := true; That do nothing.